# Who is the controller of an Aura with Enchant land placed on an opponent's land?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Say I enchant an opponent's land with [Psychic Venom](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bPsychic%20Venom%5d). Who controls the Psychic Venom, me or my opponent? This is important to know in case I want to sacrifice it to [Forbidden Ritual](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bForbidden%20Ritual%5d), for example.

Comment: Responding to your comment here, because it is about the question. Closing your question is not a punishment, and it does not imply that you should have already known that the other question existed. It is how we consolidate questions that are essentially the same. Different examples do not make questions different. If you believe that your question is asking for different information than the other one, please explain what that difference is.

Comment: Regarding my edits, I tried to keep the essence of the question the same, and make sure that it asks for the same information it originally did. If I missed the mark with that, you can make your own edits or even revert my edit, or explain your specific objections to the change I made. The answer was posted and edited into its current form before I made my edit, so my edit did not influence it at all.

Comment: We would also like to point out that this question can be a duplicate of another should be considered a punishment ...! What kind of thinking... Remember Murgatroid, I am also and only a "new contributor", I have been writing on this site for less than a month. So please Murgatroid, read the Code of Conduct more accurately...

Comment: You came to this site looking for an answer to your question. Closing as a duplicate is our way of showing both you and future visitors where that answer can already be found. If it's not really a duplicate, it's important that you explain what specifically is different, both so that we understand why it should be reopened and so that we know what information is missing in the other answers that should be included in the answers here.

Comment: No, this time I agree with the duplicate - I asked this question without knowing there was a similar question, already asked. But I disagree with the other question duplication...the one concerning Singing Bell Strike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the aura remains under your control even if it enchants an opponents land and you can sacrifice it to forbidden ritual.

from the comprehensive rules:

> 303.4e An Aura’s controller is separate from the enchanted object’s controller or the enchanted player; the two need not be the same. If an Aura enchants an object, changing control of the object doesn’t change control of the Aura, and vice versa. Only the Aura’s controller can activate its abilities. However, if the Aura grants an ability to the enchanted object (with “gains” or “has”), the enchanted object’s controller is the only one who can activate that ability.

In general, if you cast the spell and the spell creates a permanent (as with enchantments, creatures, artifacts and so on) the permanent will be under your control unless the card says something different.

Comment: I'm confused by this part: "...if the opponent sacrifices the land that Psychic Venom is attached to...Psychic Vemon will be destroyed..."  I don't see anything in the card text that would destroy it.  If you are talking about it going to the graveyard since the land is gone (which is not technically destroying it), then even that is not true.  Auras' attachment is checked as a State-Based Action, and those don't happen until Forbidden Ritual has finished resolving.  It would not be good to leave it there without sacrificing it after that since otherwise it will go to the graveyard, though.

Comment: huh, i suppose you are right. i will remove that passage

Comment: I really disegree the duplication.How do I know that this question had already been asked?Although,in my opinion in an absolutely different form, a very different example.In this case,Forbidden Ritual is well explained,and its application to a similar case to that of the question "Who controls negative enchantments?,too". More than this, Nom4d3  has misunderstood because Murgatroid editing was excessive ...please Murgatroid,next time do not change it too much:I understand that I write too long questions,but this way other users who want to answer can understand the question without any doubt.

Comment: Ok, Murgatroid, it is correct - I missed the exact moment of Nomad edited answer sending, and your question editing too, because I wasn't online that moment. If they're in time-inverted, and if it is going this way only, then you're right.